# annoying message in new-distributiongroup powershell command "new! microsoft 365 groups"

Tags: powershell

When im using command "new-distributiongroup" for Exchange Online before the result I'm always get annoying banner says:
"New! Microsoft 365 Groups are the next generation of distribution lists.
Groups give teams shared tools for collaborating using email, files, a calendar, and more.
You can start right away using the New-UnifiedGroup cmdlet.
"
and then the result.

i need someway to hide it because the result i receiving from the command i encoding to Base64 and sending to some server so it could decode from Base64 and write the answer..

that's how it looks:
New! Microsoft 365 Groups are the next generation of distribution lists.
Groups give teams shared tools for collaborating using email, files, a calendar, and more.
You can start right away using the New-UnifiedGroup cmdlet.
eyJwcm9jZXNz4aXRfY29kZdfgwicHJvY2Vzc19sYXN0X21lc3NhZ2UiOiJEaXN0cmlidXRpb24gR3JvdXAgYWJvdCBidXQgdGVzdCdfgB3YXRlZCBzdWNzZnVsbHkifQ==

and should be just:
eyJwcm9jRfY29kZSI6MCwicHJvY2Vsfsfzc19sYXN0X21lc3NhZ2UiOiJEaXN0cmlidXRpb24gR3JvdXAgYWJvdCBidXQgdGVzdCB3YXMgY3JlYsdfXRlZCBzdnVsbHkifQ==
(base64 code is for example)

found some topics several years ago, with same problem, but was no answer.
thanks

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but would redirecting the information stream to $null help? `6> $null`  [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection)

Comment: tried, not working((
thanks for advice